# Как убрать появление клавиатуры в textView при возврате на viewController

Tags: swift, textview

Есть `recordController` в нем кнопка Сохранить и 2 `textView`, туда вносятся данные и понажатую на кнопку эти данные сохраняются в Firebase и проходит переход на другой `viewController`. Переход осуществляется `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0`. После нажатия на Сохранить и повторном переходе на recordController самопроизвольно появляется клавиатура от textView. Как ее свернуть полностью при срабатываниии метода `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0`?

Comment: Сам задал и сам решил. Добавляем `textView.resignFirstResponder()`